# Play music if not playing, but don't if it is already playing (Xcode,Swift4)

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode10

I got a question about the `AVFoundation` and `AVAudioPlayer`.

In my project I have a view where you start in and a second on where the action happens. When I start the app I told the first view to start playing my background music and it has to continue when the user is in the second view. But whenever you come back to the first view it starts the song again, even though it is already playing. So I end up with a lot of echos.
How can I prevent that from happening?

Here is my code that I have yet:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class StartViewController: UIViewController {
    var backgroundPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //background music file
        let sound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "background_music", ofType: "mp3")

        do {
            backgroundPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: sound!))
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }

        playBackgorundMusic()
    }

    func playBackgorundMusic() {
        if backgroundPlayer.isPlaying {
            //do nothing
        } else {
            backgroundPlayer.play()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to play pause your play multiple `ViewController` then implement Play Pause code in `AppDelegate` so you can easily play pause player.

Comment: How do you switch between the two view controllers? Because if you push and dismiss the second view controller on your first one, this should work properly already.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a **singleton class** for Music player to maintain state like play, pause, stop etc.

```
class MusicPlayerManager{

    static let shared = MusicPlayerManager()
    var backgroundPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    init(){}

    func playMusic(){
        if backgroundPlayer.isPlaying {
            //do nothing
        } else {
            backgroundPlayer.play()
        }
    }

}
```